# bash- Read an array then write from that point for some number of elements to a file

Tags: bash

I need to search through an array then once I find what I'm looking, read that
element plus a couple more of the same array and write all to a file.

This is what I have so far

```sh
if [ -e "${EPH_DIR}" ]
then
  i=0
  while read line
  do
    FILE[$i]="$line"
    i=$(($i+1))
  done < ${EPH_DIR}
fi

for i in ${FILE[*]}
do
  echo "$i"
  if [[ $i == ${SAT} ]]
  then
    echo "Found it: $i"
  fi
done
```

Comment: And how is it failing? At the least you'll probably want `"${FILE[@]}"` instead of `${FILE[*]}`

Comment: Cairnarvon - Thanks for the editing help...much appreciated. :)

Comment: Kevin-  I find the elenent I'm looking for however I need to also get the following 2 elements.  Here's what the file I'm reading looks like:O3B M001
1 11111U   09008D 12250.00000000  .00000000  00000-0  00000-0 0    83
2 11111   0.0001   0.0000 0000001   0.0000   0.0000  5.00300000  1053
O3B M002
1 11112U   09008D 12250.00000000  .00000000  00000-0  00000-0 0    84
2 11112   0.0001  15.0000 0000001   0.0000   0.0000  5.00300000  1050

Comment: youre probably looking for this: `${FILE[@]:$i:2}` - take two elements of array from the positiom `$i`

Comment: This is where I'm at with finding the elements I'm looking for:   O3B M001
1 11111U   09008D 12250.00000000  .00000000  00000-0  00000-0 0    83
2 11111   0.0001   0.0000 0000001   0.0000   0.0000  5.00300000  1053
O3B M002
Found it: O3B M002


1 11112U   09008D 12250.00000000  .00000000  00000-0  00000-0 0    84
2 11112   0.0001  15.0000 0000001   0.0000   0.0000  5.00300000  1050
O3B M003

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a C-style for-loop:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#FILES[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${FILES[i]} == $SAT ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "found it" "${FILES[i]}" "${FILES[i+1]}" "${FILES[i+2]}"
    fi
done
```

Note that the array index in brackets is an arithmetic expression, so the dollar sign is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `grep` switch `-A`:

> ```
>    -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>           Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.
> ```

Just pipe out the contents of the array into `grep` and use `-A` to give you however many extra lines you'd like printed.  For example, use `-A2` to print two additional lines after any line matching `$STAT`:

```
printf -- '%s\n' "${FILE[@]}" | grep -A2 "^$SAT$"
```

If you want this to go out to a new file, like the question's title suggests, then just redirect this to where you want:

```
printf -- '%s\n' "${FILE[@]}" | grep -A2 "^$SAT$" > /path/to/my/file
```

Since it looks like your array is just taking a file listing from the directory `$EPH_DIR`, instead of using a loop, you could put the listing into the array by doing:

```
FILE=( "$(ls $EPH_DIR)" )
```

Or, if this printing is the only thing you're using the array for, you can skip the array entirely and just send the directory listing directly into `grep`:

```
ls $EPH_DIR | grep -A2 "^$SAT$"
```